What do I do with the ground wire when I replace a two prong cord with a three prong one?
My father in law gave me an old corded Dewalt orbital sander. It's rated at 120 volts and says it draws 2 amps. The attached power cord is a two prong (hot and neutral), and it's terrible. FIL says his dad didn't treat it well. Cord is really broken - insulation coming off, internal wires exposed in places, and so forth. Definitely don't want to use that cord.
FIL also gave me a spare three prong power cord. Three prong plug on the one end, open wires on the other end. Size says it's clearly way more than capable as far as amp draw is concerned.
I think that replacing the cord shouldn't be too difficult. Just pull out the old one, put in the new one, and don't expose anything important. Dunno if I'll need to solder anything or not.
My main question for you all, then, is "What do i do with the (unused) grounding wire in the cord?". Do i just wrap it in electrical tape and proceed to ignore it?

Is this a double insulated tool with complete plastic housing on the outside(no metal)?  If so ground wire is useless on it.  Larger gauge wire is good, but a proper two prong power cord is only a few dollars.

crip659 - yes it's double insulated. Yes the 14 guage (15 amp) power wire is overkill. It's what i have at the moment.

Do you have a model #?

Can just snip the ground wire at the tool.  The ground is for your safety only, but that is provided by the double insulation.  14 gauge is not too large.
